# matrices are not aligned with np.dot

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, matrix, dot

I have this matrix that represents my "hat matrix".

```
dfPruebas_hat = dfPruebas.dot(np.linalg.inv(dfPruebas_T.dot(dfPruebas)).dot(dfPruebas_T))
dfPruebas_hat
```

in which i obtain something like this (the "1" are only for representation, the numbers of the whole matrix are similar to those of the first row)

| firm | 0 | 1 | 2 | 3 | 4 | 5 | ... | 784 | 785 | 786 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| AA | 0.010155 | -0.003447 | -0.000309 | 0.002508 | 0.001182 | 0.000012 | ... | 0.000688 | 0.001303 | 0.001651 |
| AL | 42 | 1 | 1 | 1 | 1 | 1 | ... | 1 | 1 | 1 |
| ... | 42 | 1 | 1 | 1 | 1 | 1 | ... | 1 | 1 | 1 |
| ZL | 42 | 1 | 1 | 1 | 1 | 1 | ... | 1 | 1 | 1 |
| ZZ | 42 | 1 | 1 | 1 | 1 | 1 | ... | 1 | 1 | 1 |

787 rows × 787 columns

The other variable i have is "y_1"

```
#Outliers
y_i = df_ServiceLast['RNQ']
y_i
```

Where I obtain this

| firm |  |
| --- | --- |
| AA | -0.514447 |
| AL | -0.098678 |
| ... | ... |
| ZL | -0.982014 |
| ZZ | -3.482115 |

Name: RNQ, Length: 787, dtype: float64

The problem comes when I perform the operation I need with numpy.dot

```
y_hat = dfPruebas_hat.dot(y_i)
y_hat
```

where I get this error

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-43-b015387bbaa7> in <module>
----> 1 y_hat = dfPruebas_hat.dot(y_i)
      2 y_hat

/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/pandas/core/frame.py in dot(self, other)
   1444             common = self.columns.union(other.index)
   1445             if len(common) > len(self.columns) or len(common) > len(other.index):
-> 1446                 raise ValueError("matrices are not aligned")
   1447 
   1448             left = self.reindex(columns=common, copy=False)

ValueError: matrices are not aligned
```

and I'm not sure why this is happening, or what the problem might be, or if there's any other way to do it.

Comment: Did you (re)read the pandas `.dot` documentation?

Comment: The alilgnment rules for `np.dot` are clear, but you are using the `dot` method of a dataframe.  So the message is different.